# Can tikz coordinates be exported to a text-file?

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

Can tikz coordinates be exported to a text file, while the document is rendered?
Let the document be:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate(vertexA) at (0, 10);
    \coordinate(vertexB) at (5, 8);
    \coordinate(vertexC) at (2.5, 0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I would be glad to have a text file containing page numbers and absolute coordinates of each named point in tikz. It could look like this: (Table formatting is for illustration, but not important.)

```
label   | page | top | left | unit
--------+------+-----+------+------
vertexA |    1 | 128 |   54 | pt
--------+------+-----+------+------
vertexB |    1 | ... |  ... | pt
--------+------+-----+------+------
vertexC |    1 | ... |  ... | pt
```

In the end, I'd like to create test forms for my students. They should answer multiple choice questions by filling small circles. By knowing, where the circles are, I can scan and examine the result sheets with the help of a computer program. (I know how to do machine vision yet, but not, how to export coordinates in tikz.)

Comment: For your final purpose it seems to me that it would be easier to use a picture treatment software rather than exporting coordinates and compare them. For instance you could scan the answer sheet with the right answers and compare the scanned sheets from your students to this one with an appropriate software.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This leaves the coordinates in scaled points (65536 sp = 1 pt) in a `.pos` file:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newwrite\posfile
\immediate\openout\posfile=\jobname .pos
\newcommand\coordpos[1]{%
\node at (#1) {\pdfsavepos\write\posfile{#1: \the\pdflastxpos, \the\pdflastypos}}
}
\begin{document} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate(vertexA) at (0, 10);
    \coordinate(vertexB) at (5, 8);
    \coordinate(vertexC) at (2.5, 0);
    \coordpos{vertexA};
    \coordpos{vertexB};
    \coordpos{vertexC};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

resulting in

```
vertexA: 6830544, 49603716
vertexB: 16153939, 45874358
vertexC: 11492241, 30956926
```

Comment: Why do you have to ruin my longer and more obscure answer using `pgfplotstable` etc. ? :P Oh, and pgf has a temporary openout handle named `\w@pgf@writea`

Comment: Hello percusse, have you answered something before David Carlisle? I don't see any other answer, so I'm confused to read that he should have ruined your answer. I'd be interested in your approach as well.

Comment: Dear David Carlisle, thank you very much. That really did it; you helped me a lot! I added an `\thepage` in front of the coords in order to know about the current page number. Now I can start with creating the tests! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9):

Here is my super redundant answer if compared to David's typical witty hack (though it is possible to break his scheme only if we try hard). But it doesn't use a write handler instead it updates a `.txt` file via `pgfplotstable`

### What did I do?

I start updating a TikZ picture counter (though `\pgfpictureid` also does that but I don't want to touch it) and I also count the number of nodes in the TikZ picture for later use.

At the end of each TikZ picture, I get the page number, the node original name and its top and left positions and write to a temporary table. Then I `vertcat` with the previous table written to `pointlist.txt`. And I rewrite that file with the updated table. I reset the node counter and wait for the next picture.

### How to use

You add `relevant` to the TikZ pictures that you want to enable the recording and in the relevant pictures you add `atl` to the nodes and coordinates. That will give you the txt file in the same folder with name `pointlist.txt` you can also typeset it in the TeX file as given below.

### The code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[user]{zref}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

%======================= Here we go ==============================
\newcounter{mypiccount}\setcounter{mypiccount}{0}
\newcounter{mypointcount}\setcounter{mypointcount}{0}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    relevant/.prefix style={
        remember picture,
        execute at begin picture={\zlabel{\pgfpictureid}},
        execute at end picture={%
            \pgfplotstableset{
                 create on use/label/.style={create col/assign/.code={
                     \edef\myentry{\expandafter\csname nnn\themypiccount\number\numexpr\pgfplotstablerow+1\relax\endcsname}
                     \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\myentry}
                    }
                }, 
                 create on use/top/.style={create col/assign/.code={
                     \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current page}{north west}}%
                         {\pgfpointanchor{nnn-\themypiccount-\number\numexpr\pgfplotstablerow+1\relax}{center}}
                     \edef\myentry{\the\pgf@y}
                     \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\myentry}
                     }
                 },
                 create on use/left/.style={create col/assign/.code={
                     \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{current page}{north west}}%
                         {\pgfpointanchor{nnn-\themypiccount-\number\numexpr\pgfplotstablerow+1\relax}{center}}
                     \edef\myentry{\the\pgf@x}
                     \pgfkeyslet{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{\myentry}
                     }
                 },                
                 create on use/page/.estyle={create col/set={\zpageref{\pgfpictureid}}},
            }%
            \pgfplotstablenew[columns={label,page,top,left}]{\themypointcount}{\mytemptable}%
            \ifnum\themypiccount>1\pgfplotstablevertcat{\mytemptable}{pointlist.txt}\else\fi%
            \pgfplotstablesave[columns={label,page,top,left}]{\mytemptable}{pointlist.txt}
            \pgfplotstableclear{\mytemptable}%
            \setcounter{mypointcount}{0}%
        },
        execute at begin picture={%
            \stepcounter{mypiccount}\setcounter{mypointcount}{0}%
        }
    },
    atl/.style={/utils/exec={\stepcounter{mypointcount}},
                alias={nnn-\themypiccount-\themypointcount},
                append after command={\pgfextra{\expandafter\xdef\csname nnn\themypiccount\themypointcount\endcsname{\tikz@last@fig@name}}}
    }
}
\makeatother
%======================= That was weird ==============================


\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[relevant]
    \node[atl] (vertexA) at (0, 10) {A};
    \node[atl] (vertexB) at (5, 8) {B};
    \node (vertexC) at (2.5, 0) {C};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-6]

  \begin{tikzpicture}[relevant]
    \node[atl] (vertexA) at (0, 10) {A};
    \node[atl] (vertexB) at (5, 8) {B};
    \node[atl] (vertexD) at (2, 8) {D};
    \node (vertexC) at (2.5, 0) {C};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[relevant]
    \node[atl,circle] (vertexA) at (0, 10) {A};
    \node[atl] (vertexB) at (5, 8) {B};
    \node[atl] (vertexD) at (2, 8) {D};
    \node (vertexC) at (2.5, 0) {C};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1-3]

  \begin{tikzpicture}[relevant]
    \node[atl] (vertexB) at (5, 8) {B};
    \node (vertexD) at (2, 8) {D};
    \node[atl] (vertexC) at (2.5, 0) {C};
  \end{tikzpicture}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{pointlist.txt}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{
\draw[thick,red] (current page.north west) -- ++(193.76636pt,-160.42473pt);
\draw[thick,blue] (current page.north west) -- ++(122.63449pt,-388.04668pt);
}
\end{document}
```

This gives

[image]

A few items to consider:

- I've removed the unit column because the entries of dimension columns already have `pt` involved (nice try to make a bad thing look good :P)
- I did a few terrible things such as using numbers in macros etc. But getting the original names of the nodes are always boring and terrible. It might be one of the rare things I truly dislike about TikZ. But this is a design choice to allow for lots of nonletter chars in the node names.
- <strike>For some reason when I want to initialize a one row table it always produces two rows I don't know why.</strike> Not relevant any more.
- <strike>As given in the MWE, it is possible to fool the `\thepage` counter if TeX decides the picture is too big and pushes it to the next page. The counters are still 2 but the pictures are on Page 3. I remember fixing it with some `zref` module but I couldn't find it.</strike>
- If you scale the picture, the distances are not updated because I didn't consider the transformation so there is some (more) fragility.

### Things to do

- <strike>Remove the initial table rows with `-` entries. Then it is possible to sort wrt to page column.</strike> Now the table can be sorted.
- <strike>Find that `zref` thingy</strike> **FIXED**

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that creates a table in the form of

```
<coordinate name> <picture id> <page> <x_pic> <y_pic> <x_cipic> <y_cipic> <x> <y>
```

where

- `<coordinate name>` is the coordinate’s name;
- `<picture id>` is the ID of the picture (a incrementing value with every `\pgfpicture` and thus `\tikzpicture`);
- `<page>` is the page number;
- `<x_pic>` and `<y_pic>` are the coordinates of the origin of picture `<picture id>`’s origin;
- `<x_cipic>` and `<y_cipic>` are the coordinates of the coordinate inside the picture; and
- `<x>` and `<y>` are the coordinate of the coordinate on the page from the lower-left corner.

This needs `remember picture` on the picture from which you want to save the coordinates.

This solution can be used outside of any picture.

### Code

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\pgfpicture{\edef\pgfpictureid{pgfid\the\pgf@picture@serial@count}}{\edef\pgfpictureid{pgfid\the\pgf@picture@serial@count:\the\c@page}}{}{}
\tikzset{
  export coordinates/.style 2 args={%
    /utils/exec={\begingroup
          \pgftransformreset
          \immediate\openout\w@pgf@writea=#2\relax},
    @export coordinates/.list={#1},
    /utils/exec={\immediate\closeout\w@pgf@writea
        \endgroup}},
  @export coordinates/.code=\tikz@expc@export{#1}%
}
\def\tikz@expc@export#1{%
  \expandafter\let\expandafter\pgf@temp\csname pgf@sh@pi@#1\endcsname
  \expandafter\tikz@expc@split\pgf@temp\pgf@stop
  \pgfsys@getposition{\csname pgf@sh@pi@#1\endcsname}\tikz@expc@original@picture%
  \pgfextract@process\tikz@expc@original@picture{\tikz@expc@original@picture}%
  \pgfextract@process\tikz@expc@coordinpic{\let\pgf@shape@interpictureshift\pgfutil@gobble\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
  \tikz@expc@original@picture \pgf@xa\pgf@x \pgf@ya\pgf@y
  \tikz@expc@coordinpic
  \pgf@xb\pgf@x \pgf@yb\pgf@y \pgf@xc\pgf@x \pgf@yc\pgf@y
  \advance\pgf@xc\pgf@xa \advance\pgf@yc\pgf@ya
  %
  \immediate\write\w@pgf@writea{#1 \tikz@expc@pid\space\tikz@expc@page\space
    \the\pgf@xa\space\the\pgf@ya\space
    \the\pgf@xb\space\the\pgf@yb\space
    \the\pgf@xc\space\the\pgf@yc}}%
\def\tikz@expc@split pgfid#1:#2\pgf@stop{%
  \def\tikz@expc@pid{#1}%
  \def\tikz@expc@page{#2}}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \coordinate[label=A](vertexA) at (0, 10);
    \coordinate[label=B](vertexB) at (5, 8);
    \coordinate[label=C](vertexC) at (2.5, 0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{export coordinates={vertexA,vertexB,vertexC}{coordsA.dat}}

  \pagebreak

  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
    \coordinate[label=A](vertexA') at (0, 10);
    \coordinate[label=B](vertexB') at (5, 8);
    \coordinate[label=C](vertexC') at (2.5, 0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{export coordinates={vertexA,vertexB,vertexC,vertexA',vertexB',vertexC'}{coordsB.dat}}
\end{document}
```

### Output of `coordsB.dat`

```
vertexA 1 1 108.33208pt 461.03311pt 0.0pt 284.52744pt 108.33208pt 745.56055pt
vertexB 1 1 108.33208pt 461.03311pt 142.26372pt 227.62195pt 250.5958pt 688.65506pt
vertexC 1 1 108.33208pt 461.03311pt 71.13185pt 0.0pt 179.46393pt 461.03311pt
vertexA' 2 2 108.33208pt 461.03311pt 0.0pt 284.52744pt 108.33208pt 745.56055pt
vertexB' 2 2 108.33208pt 461.03311pt 142.26372pt 227.62195pt 250.5958pt 688.65506pt
vertexC' 2 2 108.33208pt 461.03311pt 71.13185pt 0.0pt 179.46393pt 461.03311pt
```

Answer (score 3):

The approach with `\pdfsavepos` has also been used in the Auto Multiple Choice project. Perhaps you can have a look at its [web site](http://home.gna.org/auto-qcm/index.en), and consider joining the project? It allows to shuffle questions and answers, get results from scans, and produce annotated completed answer sheets.