# How to selectively tell tikz that a node should acquire its coordinate by adding all coordinates of all enclosing tikzpictures?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, coordinates

There should be a recommended/standard/usual way to do (what is suggested by) the following:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (tikzpicture0) at (0pt,100pt) []{
     \begin{tikzpicture}
                \ABSOLUTE-AND-CONTEXT-AWARE-node (node00) at (0pt,0pt) []{(0pt,0pt)};
                \node (node01) at (0pt,10pt)[]{(0pt,10pt)};
     \end{tikzpicture}               
  };
  \node (tikzpicture1) at (100pt,200pt) []{
     \begin{tikzpicture}    
                \node (node10) at (0pt,0pt) []{(0pt,0pt)};
                \node (node11) at (0pt,10pt)[]{(0pt,10pt)};
     \end{tikzpicture}                              
  };
  \node (tikzpicture2) at (200pt,300pt) []{
     \begin{tikzpicture}        
                \node (node20) at (0pt,0pt) []{(0pt,0pt)};
                \node (node21) at (0pt,10pt)[]{(0pt,10pt)};
     \end{tikzpicture}                                             
  };
  \draw[->] (node00)--($(node10)+(100pt,200pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

where ABSOLUTE is supposed to mean that (node00) can be referenced outside the tikzpicture in which it was defined, and AND-CONTEXT-AWARE is supposed to mean that the coordinate (0pt,100pt) of the enclosing tikzpicture is added to the node's coordinate (0pt,0pt).

Of course, the code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (tikzpicture0) at (0pt,100pt) []{
     \begin{tikzpicture}
                \node (node00) at (0pt,0pt) []{(0pt,0pt)};
                \node (node01) at (0pt,10pt)[]{(0pt,10pt)};
     \end{tikzpicture}               
  };
  \node (tikzpicture1) at (100pt,200pt) []{
     \begin{tikzpicture}    
                \node (node10) at (0pt,0pt) []{(0pt,0pt)};
                \node (node11) at (0pt,10pt)[]{(0pt,10pt)};
     \end{tikzpicture}                              
  };
  \node (tikzpicture2) at (200pt,300pt) []{
     \begin{tikzpicture}        
                \node (node20) at (0pt,0pt) []{(0pt,0pt)};
                \node (node21) at (0pt,10pt)[]{(0pt,10pt)};
     \end{tikzpicture}                                             
  };
  \draw[->] (node00)--($(node10)+(100pt,200pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

yields

[image]

while the intended illustration should look like the (hard-coded-coordinate-obtained-) illustration

[image]

What do you recommend?

Comment: First recommendation is that don't nest TikZ pictures.  There is always another way. Actually I don't even know why you nested them here.

Comment: your image I reproduce width `\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, fit}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every node/.append style = {align=center}
                        ]
\node (n0) at (0pt,  0pt)       {(0pt,10pt)\\ (0pt,0pt)};
\node (n1) at (100pt,100pt)     {(0pt,10pt)\\ (0pt,0pt)};
\node (n2) at (200pt,200pt)     {(0pt,10pt)\\ (0pt,0pt)};
  \draw[->] (n0.center) -- (n1.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`. Is this what you looking for? Please, clarify your question.

Comment: Instead of nesting pictures you can use `scope` to move around parts of codes.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. @percusse: re "don't nest TikZ pictures. There is always another way.": I see that there always is another way, but I wonder what a _canonical/easy/systematic_ way is: in short, the main issue are _equally named nodes_. I have to work with a rather large number of separate TikZ pictures. I have to combine some of them into one TikZ picture. Wrapping them into nodes within the ambient TikZ picture (pragmatically-)works, in particular, neutralizes the equally-named nodes in the constituent TikZ pictures---except that it violates your advice.

Comment: Of course, one solution is to systematically edit all the  TikZ pictures in the "pool" to disambiguate all node-names. However, this is much work to do, and rather inflexible (think of an "on-line" scenario, in which someone hands you new TikZ pictures, with nodes named according to his/her personal whim, and you have to incorporate those small TikZ pictures into the larger one. @StefanH: Do scopes have name-spaces of their own? (I know that this could be answered easily by experimenting, but it seems not wrong to ask it here.) Moreover, what do you think is a recommendable way to combine

Comment: [...] to combine a large number of small "legacy" TikZ pictures (without any guarantees that there may be node-names repeated) into one large TikZ picture?

Comment: Node names are global within the picture, so the names in the scope can be used in the whole picture environment. But there can be some names used only in the scope, then they can be overwritten in another part or scope. You can also add an argument that is appended to the node name and in such a way get unique names even if the same module is loaded multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general advice is not to use nested `tikzpicture`s. You can do the same using `scope` instead. In the code below I added some names to your nodes, just to differ them. Arrow at the end of your code does not five the arrow in your hardcoded picture since its endpoint is derived from `node10` and not `node01`. I added one in red using `node01` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (node00) at (0pt,0pt) []{N00:(0pt,0pt)};
  \node (node01) at (0pt,10pt)[]{N01:(0pt,10pt)};
  \begin{scope}[shift={(100pt,200pt)}]
    \node (node10) at (0pt,0pt) []{N10:(0pt,0pt)};
    \node (node11) at (0pt,10pt)[]{N11:(0pt,10pt)};  
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[shift={(200pt,300pt)}]
    \node (node20) at (0pt,0pt) []{N20:(0pt,0pt)};
    \node (node21) at (0pt,10pt)[]{N21:(0pt,10pt)};
  \end{scope}
  \draw[->] (node00)--($(node10)+(100pt,200pt)$) node[anchor=west]{(N10)+(100pt,200pt)};
  \draw[red,->] (node00)--($(node01)+(100pt,200pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for the advice. @StefanH: re "In the code below I added some names to your nodes, just to differ them": this is an issue relevant to what I write in my comment to the OP; see above.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand this correctly there is a problem with your concept. Let's have a look at the following case:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (10,10) {This was 10, 10};
\node at (15,15) {This was 15, 15};
\draw (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This will give us

[image]

A couple of things to notice: the resulting box does not have a size of 15x15 though it has the largest distance to the origin. And also it doesn't have 5x5 either because of the text length.

So it will not be possible to find where the nodes are absolutely relative to the final canvas unless you fix the bounding box beforehand. The remaining solution would be hacking into the node placement and including the current bounding box values and self size and updating everything accordingly. Even then if I place something at `(-2,-2)` now all node values need to be updated because the bounding box now suddenly becomes 17ish x 17ish. So node placement should be delayed until the whole picture is typeset. And we have not even touched the transformations such as scaling and translations.

Thus, my opinion is that this won't fly with straightforward manipulations. I reiterate the general mantra: Don't nest TikZ pictures. There is always another way.

Your actual problem (whatever that might be) that motivated this direction probably could be solved by the answers of [Can tikz coordinates be exported to a text-file?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130931/can-tikz-coordinates-be-exported-to-a-text-file) with a two pass solution.